# Managing SIM cards from multiple countries

Tags: cellphones, recommendations, shopping

I've found myself amassing a collection of SIM cards from my travels to different countries, and it's starting to become unmanageable.

Currently, I'm using plastic bags.  Each SIM card goes in its own bag with a label indicating the country and phone number associated with it.  It works, but it's somewhat bulky to store and difficult to sort through.

How can I keep my SIM cards organized in a way that I can carry a collection with me, keep them organized by country and be able to quickly and easily locate the one I need?

Comment: This is currently worded as a forum post soliciting anecdotes from various people. This makes it fall afoul of both our rules about not being subjective, chattiness, and especially "no one correct answer". See if you can reword it in a way that it would have a definite answer. Otherwise I think it would be better in our chatroom or on a travel forum. (It is a good question just not for Stack Exchange's format.)

Comment: Does that even make much sense? Some prepaid cards i used expired after they haven't been used for a year....

Comment: Depends how much you travel around. I have about two dozen sim cards for less than 10 countries. If you travel around with an 3G iPad, 3G dongle and phone, you might have up to three sim cards per country.

Comment: @hippietrail Updated with some "best answer" criteria.  Let me know if I need to be more specific.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was a flight attendant before and I had this problem. I just kept losing them. Then I came up with an idea--An empty cigarette pack. Just put the sim cards inside the plastic that covers the pack and its tight enough to hold it. But then I saw a good thing that really helped me a lot. Its a sim card holder that can hold up to 4 sim cards, Its exactly the size of a credit card and so thin so you can put it in your wallet for easy access. Here is a photo:

[image: Sim Holder]

I got it for like 3 or 4 dollars.

Regarding the labels, you can buy small stickers and put them there. You have plenty of space in the holder to stick labels and write some info for each sim card.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I've been looking for, for years.

Comment: Where can one purchase something like this, and what is it called?

Comment: check this, its even better http://www.amazon.com/Link-Depot-LD-MCHOLDER-Memory-Carrying/dp/B000ZD0CV4/ref=pd_bxgy_e_img_b